# how to replace link in the text with own anchor

Tags: php, preg-replace

I need to replace whole link with the anchor ($2)
smth like

```
preg_replace('\<a.*?href="(.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>\', '$2', $text)
```

but only if ($1) is matches with part of my link

I can use something like this 
`\<a.*?href="(.*?my\.link.*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>\` only if text

`"some text <a href="http://my.link/?action">anchor</a> some text"`

but in this case it's not ok at all

`"some text <a href="http://another.link/?action">anchor</a> some another text <a href="http://my.link/?action">anchor</a>"`

here my solution will replace both links with last anchor

Comment: I think it works https://3v4l.org/kjQ9E Perhaps it seems that way because the text is `anchor`?

Comment: but i need to us part of the link in regex (.*?my\.link.*?)

Comment: You could replace with group 1 I think https://3v4l.org/j4Mka

Comment: my aim is to replace full link (<a href ... /a>) with the anchor of this link in case of the href param is contains the part of the text i'll pass into the function
`
"\<a.*?href="(.*? " . $LINK . " .*?)".*?>(.*?)<\/a>\"
`
for example $link = "my\.link"

in this case i need to replace only second link in text with the "second anchor"

`
some text <a href="http://another.link/?action">first anchor</a> some another text <a href="http://my.link/?action">second anchor</a>
`
here is wrong example [regex101](https://regex101.com/r/5vz26t/1)